# StackOverflow-Steroids - A Chrome extension to introduce (and test) new features on Stack Overflow faster

Tags: script, chrome-extensions, editing, posts

I've previously [complained about the bad usability that Stack Exchange sites can have and **created a Chrome extension to help test possible fixes**](https://meta.stackoverflow.com/questions/295609/more-responsive-text-editor-and-fixed-position-code-editor-wait-for-the-changes). It did not attract much attention.

Now I've added a extra features and general improvements (see below).

You can [**download *StackOverflow Steroids* from the Chrome Store.**](https://chrome.google.com/webstore/detail/stackoverflow-steroids/hmpehldkjbnpdhebfangeaoabhphihic)

Comments and suggestions are welcomed, as well as contributions.
The extension is [**published at GitHub**](https://github.com/Danziger/StackOverflow-Steroids), so anyone can open a pull request with new features or improvements on the current ones.

---

I would like to know if someone is missing any important feature that he or she thinks that should be introduced as soon as possible.

The main improvements made so far are in the editor, as you can see in this screenshot:

[image: screenshot]

NOTE: This question was originally [posted over on Meta Stack Overflow](https://meta.stackoverflow.com/questions/302600/chrome-extension-as-a-way-to-introduce-and-test-new-features-faster).
[Martijn Pieters suggested to post this here](https://meta.stackoverflow.com/questions/302600/chrome-extension-as-a-way-to-introduce-and-test-new-features-faster#comment-234327) and it seems a good idea, but I did not know this forum before.

Answer (score 3):

1. You're abusing a browser action button. If you want to have an option page, just define it in your manifest as an option page. What you have now is an option page hidden behind a browser action button... :S
2. Try updating the css live. Not sure how your code works, but it makes it far easier to understand what various features do and if you're properly saving your settings there is listener you can listen on for changes.
3. It might make sense to either automatically update the length of the input field or scroll the preview field the same relative amount. Option 2 is a lot wiser probably... though I like option 1 better xD .
4. Stylish design option seems to be always turned on.

Honestly, issue #1 is for me bad enough that I am tempetd to just uninstall the extension, but I quite like the work you did on the editor as I have been considering doing the same thing myself. Oh well, guess I will just try hiding the browser action button behind the arrow for the time being.